# abreviatura de "editores": "eds."?

Tags: abreviaturas

I'm translating a scholarly article.  A footnote cites a chapter in a book.  The editors of the book are listed in the English version as "eds."  May I use that in the Spanish version as well, like this?

> X y Y, eds., *título* etc.

Comment: I've never seen that before and I wouldn't understand "eds." so I'd suggest you type the whole thing, but that could be just me.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the RAE (Royal Academy of the Spanish), the abbreviation of *Editor (editor/publisher)* or *Editorial (publishing house)* is "ed." and I guess the plural is "eds.".

So if the book was published by just one publishing house you should write "ed.", but if two publishing houses published the book together, you should use "eds.".

You can check here all the abbreviation officially recognised by the RAE: http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/apendices/abreviaturas.

Un saludo.

Comment: It's one publishing house, but two people wore the "editor" hat.

Comment: As far as I know, in Spain, the most important part is the the publishing house, the people (editors) who works on the book don't mind. So, I would write "ed." and the name of the publishing house.

Comment: Well, the book being cited was published in the U.S., where the names of the editors are more important than the name of the publisher, and the translated article that cites it will be published in Latinamerica.